# optaplanner-spring-boot-starter vs kie-server-spring-boot-starter

Tags: java, spring-boot, optaplanner

I have developed a complete working spring boot project for task assignment using **optaplanner-spring-boot-starter** as a dependency, but the requirement is to use **kie-server-spring-boot-starter-optaplanner** for the same.

I have gone through the official documentation form optaPlanner and RedHat PAM business optimizer. But still confused regarding the best solution, As integrating KIE server with spring-boot and running it over tomcat will be an effort. Also, we cannot annotate the solverManager, we need to manually create an XML and pass the constraints, when using kie-server-spring-boot-starter-optaplanner.

**Is there any example where I can find kie-server-spring-boot-starter-optaplanner integration with spring-boot?
What is the main difference between these two dependencies, In which scenarios these should be used?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to the `optaplanner-spring-boot-starter`, especially if you're already using that and happy with it. **optaplanner-spring-boot-starter is the way to use OptaPlanner on Spring Boot,** similar on how `optaplanner-quarkus` is the way to use OptaPlanner on Quarkus: it's full featured and under active maintenance. It has a *minimalist* approach to dependencies, just like any other spring boot starter, so it follows the Spring philosophy. If there's any issues with it, report it on the community optaplanner-dev mailing list.

`kie-server-spring-boot-starter-optaplanner` includes `kie-server`.
If you're integrating with jBPM for human task assignment, take a look at the integration Walter wrote for that: https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/tree/master/kie-server-parent/kie-server-services/kie-server-services-task-assigning - it's explained in the kie server documentation.

Comment: Thanks this helps, the only reason organization is forcing to use "kie-server-spring-boot-starter-optaplanner" stating redhat will provide support and even drools can be integrated within kie server, even though this will be standalone spring-boot application without any JBPM/RHPAM at all. Is it even a good design when we are developing standalone springboot for task assignments ?? any thoughts on that?

Comment: The Red Hat build of OptaPlanner includes `optaplanner-spring-boot-starter` too, see [our customer maven repository](https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/org/optaplanner/optaplanner-spring-boot-starter/). If you have a RH subscription, open a support case, our 24/7 staff will gladly help you and we can look into more details based on your detailed needs, to help you make a good choice.